# Converting two date formats in one format pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

What would be the easiest way to transform two date formats in pandas dataframe into one?
Below is my input

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': {0: '26/1/16 ', 1: '26/1/2016 '}})
```

Expected output:

```
       DOB
0   26/1/2016
1   26/1/2016
```

I need to maintain the same dateformat.

Followed the comments and used pd.to_datetime

```
pd.to_datetime(df.DOB)
```

Output:

```
0   2016-01-26
1   2016-01-26
```

Which is fine but I want to retain the original format of `%d/%m/%Y`

I have tried using the format argument after executing pd.to_datetime

```
df.DOB=pd.to_datetime(df.DOB,format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

It seems it does not changes the format.
Output:

```
0   2016-01-26
1   2016-01-26
```

If I directly execute below to provide the format it gives error which makes sense as input is not of same format

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': {0: '26/1/2016 ', 1: '26/1/2016 '}})
df.DOB=pd.to_datetime(df.DOB,format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

ERROR:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

Long story short how can I retain the original date format

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df.DOB, errors='coerce')` works just like so

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])` would do.

Comment: But in that format, if they had a date like `6/1/16` `pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])` would read in as June 1st, not January 6th

Comment: I want to keep the format. pd._to_datetime will give me date of format other than two formats in input. When I give format as an argument it throws an error @HarvIpan

Comment: @jpp I have made the explanation more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You have whitespace in your date strings. Use [`pd.Series.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) before calling `pd.to_datetime` to guarantee you will avoid errors.

#### Option 1: don't specify format

Here you don't even need to strip whitespace:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': {0: '26/1/16 ', 1: '26/1/2016 '}})

df.DOB = pd.to_datetime(df.DOB)

print(df)

         DOB
0 2016-01-26
1 2016-01-26
```

#### Option 2: strip before specifying format

Supply `format` only if you *know* beforehand the specific format of your dates. If you do this, you will need to use `pd.Series.str.strip` beforehand:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': {0: '26/1/2016 ', 1: '26/1/2016 '}})

df.DOB = pd.to_datetime(df.DOB.str.strip(), format='%d/%m/%Y')

print(df)

         DOB
0 2016-01-26
1 2016-01-26
```

Comment: White space might be a typo but still I cannot see the output in correct format.

Comment: @mad_, Sorry, I though you gave a [mcve]. Unfortunately, I can't be *sure* of the problem until you provide one..

Comment: I have provided all the scenarios above. I need the data in format of `%d/%m/%Y'. Your output is of format `%Y-%d-%d`

Comment: Use `df['DOB'] = df['DOB'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` as a final step.